# Bi-Variate discrete random variable and conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I came across the following in my textbook:

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector such that $f(y|x) =  1/x$ if $y = 1, 2, . . . , x$
($0$ elsewhere),for any positive integer $x$. Let $X$ have the following probability mass function
$f(x) = 1/3$ if $x = 1, 2, 3$ 
 ($0$ elsewhere).

Then I am trying to understand the relationship between these two statements. 
Since $f(y|x)=\frac {f(x,y)}{f_X(x)} $, then does it follow that since
$1/x=f(y|x)=\frac {f(x,y)}{1/3}$ that $f(x,y)=1/3x$?

I then wish to find $E(Y)$ but my understanding of how to do this depends on my previous result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake in your multiplication through by one third, you should have 
$$
f(x,y) = f(y|x)f(x) = \frac{1}{3x},
$$
As a check you should have $\sum_x \sum_y f(x,y) = 1$ so lets try this
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=1}^{3} \sum_{y=1}^{x} \frac{1}{3 x} &= \left(\sum_{y=1}^{1}\frac{1}{3 \cdot 1 } \right) + \left(\sum_{y=1}^{2}\frac{1}{3 \cdot 2}\right) + \left( \sum_{y=1}^{3} \frac{1}{3 \cdot 3}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3 \cdot 2} + \frac{3}{3 \cdot 3} = 1.
\end{align}
$$
Also make sure you are happy what the support of this random variable is, to make this clear in your head try sketching out the joint distribution on the lattice $ \{ (x,y) \}$, but do this by fixing a value of $x$ and then sketching a slice, which is the conditional distribution $f(y | x = k), k = 1,2,3$. Which should hopefully really clear up for you what this probability distribution looks like.